# How to get css working for samsung s5?

Tags: android, css

I have some css that does not seem to work for a samsung s5 mobile phone:

```
.app > header h1 .icon-ui-largearrow-down {
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top: 3px;
    font-size: 43px;
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleY(0.9);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #555555 !important;
}
```

To be precise the transform bit does not work on the S5, but is working for desktop though. What could be the issue?

Comment: what about other Android devices? Which version of Android? And which browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
-webkit-transform:
```

Android chrome (assuming your S5 uses this) relies on a prefix as stated on http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

> Supported with prefix: ~webkit~

Comment: How to emulate this on windows?

Comment: It should work in chrome, then inspect Ctrl+Shit+i and toggle device toolbar Ctrl+Shift+m